# onbeforeunload in JavaScript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, onbeforeunload

I seem to be having problems using onbeforeunload events to warn a user if they are navigating away from a page with unsaved form data. I've written a minimal page, which still doesn't work. This page sometimes warns me if I'm navigating away or reloading the page, but it sometimes doesn't, and I can't see what the cause is. Sometimes it asks me when I haven't changed the form value. I've looked at other questions and as far as I can see, what I'm doing is right. What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
<body>

<script>

window.onload = function() { doRecord(); };
window.onbeforeunload = function() { return doCheck(); };

setTimeout( doCheck, 5000 );;

var storeValue = "";

function doRecord()
{
  var inp = document.getElementById( "theinput" );
  storeValue = inp.value;
  console.log( "Running doRecording" );
}

function doCheck()
{
  console.log( "Running doCheck" );

  var inp = document.getElementById( "theinput" );

  console.log( "Comparing '" + storeValue + "' to '" + inp.value + "'" );

  if ( storeValue != inp.value )
  {
    console.log( "It has changed" );
    return "Are you sure that you want to leave this page, value has changed";
  }
  else
  {
    console.log( "It's OK" );
    return null;
  }
}

</script>

<h3>Form</h3>
<form id="myform" method="post" action="process.php" onsubmit="window.onbeforeunload = null" >
<input type="text" size="20" name="sometext" id="theinput" value="Change This" />
<p>
<input type=submit />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is the warning appearing only when your input is empty??

Comment: window.onload waits for images and other assets like external CSS and JS to be fully loaded. It's possible that you started editing before the onload fired so your updated value got stored in storeValue. What do the console.logs say?

Comment: Your code is working just fine

Comment: The warning appears when the input has something in it. I can see from the console.log messages that the function is correctly detecting whether or not the field has changed. There are no images or external CSS or other things to be loaded. I can see from console messages that the correct value is being stored in the variable. @Abanoub - what browser (and OS) are you using? I tested this in safari on Mac OS. EDIT: I've just tried firefox on Mac OS, and that appeared to work fine.

Comment: I'm using `Google Chrome` v52 on `ubuntu 14`

Comment: On Chrome on Mac OS, it partially works. It warns me correctly if I reload a page. But, it won't warn me if I enter a new page (or search) into the address bar.

Comment: I was hoping that I would be able to avoid using JQuery as I'd prefer my application to not be dependent on it. But, I'm starting to think that the code not work is due to browser variations. The only solution (if it even is one) may be to use JQuery.

Comment: Having experimented, I'm not sure that JQuery works. It just gives different ways of registering the handlers. Is there some sample code somewhere that I can check to see if it's my code, or inherent in these browsers.

Answer (score 0):

This code looks incorrect:
`<form id="myform" method="post" action="process.php" onsubmit="window.onbeforeunload = null" >`

Should this not be:
`<form id="myform" method="post" action="process.php" onsubmit="return (window.onbeforeunload()== null)" >`

I made this change in the fiddle I created [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3n6dxq5m/1/) this now seems OK.

Comment: This would stop the submission of the form. The OP's code is removing the unload handler so the form could load the next page. You are correct that the onsubmit should return something truthy though.

Comment: I thought OP intended this i.e. stop the form submit if the check in `window.onbeforeunload` failed, although it looks odd and I haven't seen it used this way

Comment: I believe the goal is that to avoid losing their changes, the user must submit the form rather than navigating away or closing the tab.

Comment: This is correct. I wanted to disable the onbeforeunload check in case of form submission. However, the problem occurs independently of the form being submitted. I've checked the code to:  <form id="myform" method="post" action="process.php" onsubmit="window.onbeforeunload = null; return true" >  but this hasn't affected the problem.

Comment: I tried Dhananjay's fiddle, and it doesn't work for me. I can change the text in the field, enter a new address in the address bar, navigate away, and get no warning. Sometimes I get a message, and sometimes I don't.

Comment: Just in case I'm not clear, I'm only trying to warn the user if they navigate away from the page with unsaved changes. I am not trying to validate the form contents.

Comment: It appears that the problem is getting something that work consistently across browsers. My own code worked in firefox. My code works sometimes in Safari, but sometimes not (that was my first question.) In Chrome, it seems consistent that reloading the page works, but navigating away doesn't.